# How to add a worker node from a different server in Spark Standalone Cluster

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, worker

I am using this [Python template](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark/tree/master/template/python) from Big Data Europe to run a Python application on a Spark Cluster. I tried it locally by creating an `app.py` file and a `Dockerfile` in `docker-spark/` directory

app.py:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext(master='local[*]', appName='test')
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM bde2020/spark-python-template:3.0.1-hadoop3.2

ENV SPARK_APPLICATION_PYTHON_LOCATION /app/app.py
```

I also made a change to the `docker-compose.yml` by adding a service:

```
version: '2'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:3.0.1-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
  spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:3.0.1-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
  py-spark:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - ENABLE_INIT_DAEMON=setup_spark
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
```

I run `docker-compose up` and the script runs successfully. I now want to add two different workers located in different machines. How can I achieve it within this docker-spark template?